# Testing non-java dependency with maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, external

I was wondering if it is possible to test external "non-java" dependencies with `maven`. I have a project that depends on 2 external programs (one in `C` and the other in `Python`) and I would like to include some tests to be sure that they are installed and accessible through `Java`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you actually want to know is how to do it rather than just wondering if it is possible. You should make your question more specific, which will require you to go into more detail as to how those external tools are used. Are they used in the application? Or in your build environment?

Comment: My fault, I'm using external programs with the ```ProcessBuilder``` class. I have written a class for each external process launching them through the ```start()``` method. I have already written some JUnit tests but I would like to know if there is something more specific for maven (like something similar to a make file).

Comment: You should edit the question to clarify it. So you are calling the external programs in your application? What do the unit tests do exactly (Don't be afraid to post some code.)? Its also not clear where exactly you want to test if these programs are available; I would assume that you want to know if they are available in the environment where the application is going to be deployed and executed, so a unit test (or a make file) is not really going to help with that.